# How to find Sub-Documents by Criteria + Mongoose / MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Following are two Mongoose schemas :

**EmployeeSchema :**

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    employeeDetailsId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'employeedetails'
    }
});
```

**EmployeeDetailSchema :**

```
var EmployeeDetailSchema = new Schema({
    employeeId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'employee'
    },
    statusId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'status'
    }
});
```

EmployeeDetailSchema data gets saved on demand, like when a particular status is assigned to Employee. In that case, once EmployeeDetail document is saved then corresponding EmployeeDetailID is saved back to EmployeeSchema as **employeeDetailsId**

Now there is bi-directional relationship between EmployeeSchema and EmployeeDetailSchema.

**UseCase :**

I want to fetch all Employees who are tagged with particular status. Say input Status ID is `1234` then i want to fetch all employees whose status id is `1234` in EmployeeDetail document.

Following is the approach which i tried using Mongoose :

```
exports.getEmployeesByStatus = function (req, res) {
    console.log('Status ID : ' + req.query.statusId);

    EmployeeModel.find({'employeeDetailsId.statusId': {$eq: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.statusId)}})
        .exec(function (err, result) {
            if (err)res.send('400', {message: 'Unable to fetch employees data by status. Please try again later'});

            res.jsonp(result);
        });
};
```

Result that is returned is empty array though there are employees who are assigned to some statuses. Is my querying approach with Mongoose right ?

Comment: are you using sub document or using reference of employee details model for `employeeDetailsId`?

Comment: Couple of other good questions about MongoDB : Finding Sub-Documents by Criteria : [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845191) and [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142524). Thought it might help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using reference of `EmployeeDetailSchema` for `employeeDetailsId` according to your schema design. so you can't directly compare reference model field without populate. you should populate first then compare and filter documents or can user `aggregate` function achieve your goal.

can try this one:

```
EmployeeModel.aggregate([
      {$lookup: {from: 'employeedetails', localField: 'employeeDetailsId',foreignField: '_id',as: 'details'}},
      {$match: { $and:[{ "details.statusId": { "$exists": true } },{"details.statusId": req.params.statusId}]} }
    ]).exec(function (err, result) {
            if (err) return res.send('400', {message: 'Unable to fetch employees data by status. Please try again later'});

            return res.jsonp(result);
        });
```

**N.B:** convert **String** to **ObjectId** the value of `req.params.statusId`

```
{$match: {$and: [{"details.statusId": {"$exists": true}}, {"details.statusId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.statusId)}]}}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply man, i dint even knew about `$lookup`. Went through MongoDB documents about the same n found your answer very valid to my usecase. But running the same fetched no result, its still same empty [] result. Just wanted to check if Mongoose supports `aggregate` with  `$lookup` ? Any reference documents plz.

Comment: I used it as simple query in MongoDB terminal by excluding last check in match, it gave me desired result :

`db.getCollection('employees').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "employeedetails",
          localField: "employeeDetailsId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "details"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { $and:[{ "details.statusId": { "$exists": true }}]}
   }
]);`

Comment: But the issue with previous query is : i have removed condition check for `{"details.statusId": req.params.statusId}`. On adding that it again gives same old problem : `Fetched 0 record(s)`

Comment: can you add sample document ?

Comment: /* Employee Document */
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f114e1cff44b7ab414dc1"),
    "employeeId" : "10020",
    "employeefirstname" : "Tom",
    "experienceyears" : "15",
    "employeeDetailsId" : ObjectId("583fbbfe78854dd424f0523f")
}`

/* Employee Details Document */
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583fbbfe78854dd424f0523f"),
    "employeeId" : ObjectId("583f114e1cff44b7ab414dc1"),
    "statusId" : ObjectId("583ee05a1d5161941632091a"),
    "__v" : 0
}`

Comment: Following was the query which Fetched me 0 records :

`db.getCollection('employees').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "employeedetails",
          localField: "employeeDetailsId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "details"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { $and:[{ "details.statusId": { "$exists": true }}, { "details.statusId": "583ee05a1d5161941632091a"}]}
   }
]);`

Comment: if you are using `{$match: { "details.statusId": { "$exists": true } } }` then are you getting empty?

Comment: ensure that your collection name is correct for `from: "employeedetails"`

Comment: As i mentioned in my second comment : collection name is not a problem as am getting desired result when i just remove second condition in `$match:{$and}`. Only problem i see is adding `{ "details.statusId": "583ee05a1d5161941632091a"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129511/discussion-between-shaishab-roy-and-beingsuman).