# Missing Subdocument Methods in Mongoose with Typescript

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm working on a project and need to retrieve specific subdocuments from a model by their subdocument `_id`'s. I then plan on making updates to those subdocuments and saving the main document. The mongoose subdocument documentation lists a number of methods you can call on the `parent.children` array, but methods that don't already exist in Javascript for arrays give an error saying they do not exist and it doesn't compile. I'm referencing this documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

I understand that should be able to use `.findOneAndUpdate` to make my updates, and using the `runValidators` option everything should still be validated, but I would also like to just retrieve the subdocument itself as well.

I looked at this post: [MongoDB, Mongoose: How to find subdocument in found document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142524/mongodb-mongoose-how-to-find-subdocument-in-found-document) , and I will comment that the answer is incorrect that if a subdocument schema is registered it automatically creates a collection for that schema, the collection is only made if that schema is saved separately. You cannot use `ChildModel.findOne()` and retrieve a subdocument, as the collection does not exist, there is nothing in it.

Having `IChildModel` extend `mongoose.Types.Subdocument` and having the `IParent` interface reference that instead of `IChild` and not registering the `ChildModel` does not change anything other than no longer allowing calls to `.push()` to not accept simple objects (missing 30 or so properties). Also trying `mongoose.Types.Array<IChild>` in the `IParent` interface with this method does not change anything.

Changing the `IParent` interface to use `mongoose.Types.Array<IChild>` for the `children` property allows `addToSet()` to work, but not `id()` or `create()`

I'm using Mongoose version `5.5.10`, MongoDb version `4.2.0` and Typescript version `3.4.5`

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from "mongoose";

// Connect to mongoDB with mongoose
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_HOST + "/" + process.env.DB_NAME, {useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false});

// Interfaces to be used throughout application
interface IParent {
    name: string;
    children: IChild[];
}

interface IChild {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

// Model interfaces which extend Document
interface IParentModel extends IParent, Document { }
interface IChildModel extends IChild, Document { }

// Define Schema
const Child: Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

const ChildSchema: Schema = Child;

const Parent: Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    children: [ChildSchema]
});

const ParentSchema: Schema = Parent;

// Create the mongoose models
const ParentModel = mongoose.model<IParentModel>("Parent", Parent);
const ChildModel = mongoose.model<IChildModel>("Child", Child);

// Instantiate instances of both models
const child = new ChildModel({name: "Lisa", age: 7});
const parent = new ParentModel({name: "Steve", children: [child]});

const childId = child._id;

// Try to use mongoose subdocument methods
const idRetrievedChild = parent.children.id(childId); // Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IChild[]'.ts(2339)
parent.children.addToSet({ name: "Liesl", age: 10 }); // Property 'addToSet' does not exist on type 'IChild[]'.ts(2339)
parent.children.create({ name: "Steve Jr", age: 2 }); // Property 'create' does not exist on type 'IChild[]'.ts(2339)

// If I always know the exact position in the array of what I'm looking for
const arrayRetrievedChild = parent.children[0]; // no editor errors
parent.children.unshift(); // no editor errors
parent.children.push({ name: "Emily", age: 18 }); // no editor errors
```

Answer (score 13):

Kind of a late response, but I looked through the typings and found the `DocumentArray`

```
import { Document, Embedded, Types } from 'mongoose';
interface IChild extends Embedded {
    name: string;
}

interface IParent extends Document {
    name: string;
    children: Types.DocumentArray<IChild>;
}
```

Just wanted to put this here incase anyone else needs it.

Comment: Almost, you just need to use Embedded instead of Document for IChild. This way you'll have access to Subdocument methods such as parent() and ownerDocument() in addition to the usual document methods.

Comment: cannot find `Embedded` in mongoose, is this removed ?

Comment: `Embedded` is found in `Types.Embedded`

Comment: Looks like these days (Mongoose 6) `Types.Subdocument` is what you need - `Types.Embedded` no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

**Gross:**
For now, I'm going with a very quick and dirty polyfill solution that doesn't actually answer my question:

```
declare module "mongoose" {
    namespace Types {
        class Collection<T> extends mongoose.Types.Array<T> {
            public id: (_id: string) => (T | null);
        }
    }
}
```

then we declare `IParent` as such:

```
interface IParent {
    name: string;
    children: mongoose.Types.Collection<IChild>;
}
```

Because the function `id()` already exists and typescript just doesn't know about it, the code works and the polyfill lets it compile.

**Even Grosser:** Otherwise for an even quicker and dirtier solution, when you create the parent model instance simply typecast it to `any` and throw out all typescript checks:

```
const child = new ChildModel({name: "Lisa", age: 7});
const parent: any = new ParentModel({name: "Steve", children: [child]});
const idRetrievedChild = parent.children.id(childId); // works because declared any
```

Answer (score 0):

This Example Works from the official mongoose documentation [Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/subdocuments.html)
`

```
// Subdocument definition
interface Names {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  firstName: string;
}
// Document definition
interface User {
  names: Names[];
}

// TMethodsAndOverrides
type UserDocumentProps = {
  names: Types.DocumentArray<Names>;
};
type UserModelType = Model<User, {}, UserDocumentProps>;

// Create model
const UserModel = model<User, UserModelType>('User', new Schema<User, UserModelType>({
  names: [new Schema<Names>({ firstName: String })]
}));
    
const doc = new UserModel({});
doc.names[0].ownerDocument(); // Works!
```

`